# Tell me a library that makes your every day Java programming more enjoyable

Tags: java

i Would like you to name a library that makes yor coding more enjoyable through everyday work. Is Java core language develops very slowly these days, what can you do to make up for it?

I start - [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic on StackOverflow.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com would be a better forum.

Comment: @stephen do not migrate low quality questions, instead, close them as off topic

Comment: For me its Trove4j, which has to be an especially geeky choice. ;)

Answer (score 1):

My choice would have to be [spring](http://www.springsource.com/).  It so much to the table: dependancy injection, AOP as well as integration with many different libraries to the point where spring can handle the wiring for you and you just provide a pojo for spring to call.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the Google Collections Library, which is now known as [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Comment: +1, though the collections library is just part of Guava. There's a bunch of non-collections stuff in there now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what I need to do, but I would say several of the Apache Commons libraries (Collections, DbUtils, Digester, etc).

http://commons.apache.org/